# Mid-2012 MacBook Pro Key Stuck and always-typing that key

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

My built-in keyboard won't stop sending the letter "A" (was planning to replace this key but can't even log into the machine in the meantime). Using an external keyboard, I am able to type, but I can't get the correct password because of the continuous A being submitted.

Is there a way to disable the built-in keyboard without being able to sign in?

Comment: Have you tried the simple mechanical fixes on the keyboard? Blow out any dust; tap the key 20 times, fairly firmly; spray it with contact cleaner… etc?

Comment: I have—looking at the key now, it doesn't look like anything is on it, and nothing I do seems to stop it from typing